# Regular expression for only alphabet and number but not space

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have a input text box in angular js which need to accept only alphabets and numbers but not special character as well as spaces.

For that I am using `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` but its not working as i am expecting.

$error is only for special symbol but not for spaces. what i am doing wrong here please help.

I have read some people has used " " in Regex but its to allow space.

Comment: your regex is correct, may be showing more of your code will help

Comment: Could you please show a plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: Please clarify: you want to set up different error messages for different issues? What is not working? Please provide examples to show what you need and how your code should work.

Comment: @Bhagya: Did you set the ng-trim option to *false*?

Answer (score 2):

**Give a shot to this :**

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`

**It's Tested**.

Go To Link to test again : [Regex Tested](https://regex101.com/r/FGmn5l/3)

Comment: Your regex does not match *numbers*. See *need to accept only alphabets **and numbers***.

Comment: now test.. earlier .. it slipped from mind to add numbers too... sorry for that :)

Comment: Good, but there is still no difference because a regex only will not help OP because OP regex does not match spaces either. It is input that is at fault, not the regex.

Comment: means you want to restrict user from pressing `space` button in input ? is something loke that and What OP is . ?

Comment: I do not want anything. OP is the person who asked a question.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this i hope it will work :**

Pattern : `/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/`

working example : http://regexr.com/3ecr5

If you want to match all occurrences in the string then you can use global search by defining `g` flag.

Pattern : `/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/g`

Working example : http://regexr.com/3ecr8